# SQL Server: check if specific string exists in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, dynamic, case

There is user created table type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[tpSearchCriteria] AS TABLE(
    [TableName] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [ColumnName] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [ValueString] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ValueNumeric] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [ValueDate] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [Operator] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [OperatorGroup] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [SortDirection] [nvarchar](2) NULL )
```

Every time when query is executed this table is populated with some search parameters. 
In dependance of string values in column [ColumnName] I should chose different collation. 
So, there is need to examine in [ColumnName] does it contain values like 'FirstName' or 'LastName'

I tried with some CASE and IF clauses but that is not working.

System using SQL Server 2014

Comment: "is not working"...what error do you get?

Comment: @SMor ... as you see.. it's not beyond. You are beyond with that attitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select @Collation = case when exists (select 1 from @SearchCriteria where ColumnName = 'FirstName' or ColumnName = 'Surname')
                         then COALESCE(@Collation, CAST(DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation') AS nvarchar))
                   else COALESCE('SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', CAST(DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation') AS nvarchar))
                   end
```